# MySQL & PHP: Joins & Counts

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all users from my table where access_level_id!=0. I also want to count the number of entries in another table where the user id matches a field (this could be 0 or 100).

I have:

```
SELECT users.id, count(clients.id) as count FROM $db[users] as users 
                              LEFT JOIN $db[clients] as clients ON users.id=clients.salesrep_id
                              WHERE users.access_level_id!='0'
```

This is returning just a single number (17)

Comment: This is because count is usually applied to all records. `GROUP BY` as suggested below should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group the results. Try adding `GROUP BY users.id` to your Query.